# Lower bound on $(1-\frac{1}{2n})^n > \frac{1}{2}$ when $n>1$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$?

Tags: inequality

Why is it that $(1-\frac{1}{2n})^n > \frac{1}{2}$ when $n>1$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$? The thing that is counter intuitive about this statement for me is that, as n increases, then $(1-\frac{1}{2n})^n$ decreases (since $0<1-\frac{1}{2n}<1$). However, somehow it remains lower bounder by one half.

I am looking for a proof and a strong intuition on it, since the thing that worries me the most is that I feel this should have been "obvious" but its counter intuitive for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as $n$ increases, then $(1-\frac{1}{2n})^n$ decreases (since $0<1-\frac{1}{2n}<1$).

No. True, when $n$ increases, $x^n$ decreases, for every fixed $0<x<1$. But here, one is considering $y_n=(x_n)^n$, where $x_n=1-\frac{1}{2n}$ depends on $n$. Worse, $(x_n)$ is increasing, hence the previous result can tell us nothing about the sense of variation of $(y_n)$.

To wit, $y_2=\frac9{16}\gt\frac12=y_1$, and, as it happens, the sequence $(y_n)$ is actually increasing from $y_1=\frac12$ to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y_n=\frac1{\sqrt{\mathrm e}}$.

**Edit:** In this context, consider $v_n=(1-u_n)^n$ where every $u_n$ is in $(0,1)$ and $u_n\to0$. Then, as explained above, $1-u_n\to1$ but $x^n$ decreases, for every fixed $0<x<1$, hence the asymptotic behaviour of $v_n$ can vary.

To wit, $\log v_n=n\log(1-u_n)=-nu_n+o(nu_n)$ hence, if $nu_n\to0$ then $v_n\to1$, if $nu_n\to+\infty$ then $v_n\to0$, if $nu_n\to c$ then $v_n\to\mathrm e^{-c}$, while if $nu_n$ oscillates then so does $v_n$.

A similar analysis can be applied to sequences $w_n=(1-1/n)^{c_n}$ where $c_n\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. since 1-1/2n is increasing as n increases, its hard to tell immediately what going on. Its hard to know exactly without doing explicit calculations of the derivative whether the function is increasing or decreasing. How would you decide intuitively if the exponentiation to a of something smaller than 1 is winning or if the 1-1/2n increase is determining the overall growth of the function? (thanks btw!)

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Just use Bernoulli's inequality

PS: Your statement is not true for $n=1$

Comment: omg, that worked like magic! That was awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ being an integer is irrelevant, it's true for $n > 1$.  Take logarithms of both sides, and divide by $n$: your inequality is equivalent to

$$\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{2n}\right) > \frac{-\log(2)}{n}$$

Taking $x = 1/n$, that says (for $0 < x < 1$)

$$ \log(1 - x/2) > -\log (2) x$$

The left side is strictly concave, the right side is linear, and at $x = 1$ both sides are
equal.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this would be of any significant interest.

I looked at the function in terms of a continuous variable "n". Computing the derivative, I found that it can write

x^(n-1) [1/2 + log(x)/x] with x = 1 - 1 / (2n)

Then, the derivative is always positive and the function increases from 1/2 (for n=1) and the asymptote is, as already told by Did, 1 / Sqrt[e].